# PTIJ: I live in Australia and am upside down. Where should I put my tefillin?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Should they go on my hands or my feet? I usually write with my right foot.

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, on all שלש רגלים it is prohibited to don the Tefillin.

Comment: Darn, i was hoping maybe on my 3rd foot...

Answer (score 16):

The feet are a perfectly valid location for Tefillin. See Rambam, Tefillin 4:26:

> . וְכָל הָרָגִיל בִּתְפִלִּין מַאֲרִיךְ יָמִים שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (ישעיהו לח טז) ״ה׳‎ עֲלֵיהֶם יִחְיוּ
>
> The entire foot is for Tefillin, and [one who does so] will have lengthened days etc.

As well as Eruvin 96a:

> דתניא מיכל בת כושי היתה מנחת תפילין ולא מיחו בה חכמים ואשתו של יונה היתה עולה לרגל ולא מיחו בה חכמים מדלא מיחו בה חכמים אלמא קסברי מצות עשה
>
> Michal the Kushi would don the Tefillin and there was no protest by the sages. The wife of Yona would don it in the foot and there was no protest by the sages. Since the sages did not protest, they believe it to be a positive commandment.

Comment: They didnt live in Australia. So the answer has nothing to do with where you live. I would add the opposite. That was the reason the sages didnt protest.

Comment: kal vachomer... if in the N Hemisphere the sages allow it and approve etc. how much more so in the S hemisphere?

Answer (score 10):

Since you are in Australia, it would also be night time, and one does not wear tefillin at [night](https://www.etzion.org.il/en/wearing-tefillin-night).

Comment: I respectfully disagree with this answer.  It implies that at McMurdo Station, one may not wear tefillin the entire Antarctic night.  I believe it's been established that in conditions where sunrise and sunset vary dramatically from local time, one should don tefillin (and do other time-of-day-bound mitzvot) according to the official local time.